# How to hide general ui elements in frappe framework / erpnext

Tags: erpnext, frappe

What is the best approach to hide general ui options from certain desk users with lower permission roles? I would for example like to block the create workspace feature (and hide the button) for a certain user role:
[image]

Ideally I would like to also hide certain options from the following pane for certain user roles.

[image]

What would be the best approach for this. I am thinking of writing some javascript code to manipulate the dom here, but I am wondering what the best way would be to inject something like this and if it is possible to selectively inject that code in frappe framework via a custom app.

Comment: I think you need create custom app and override the some file, I add some feature to the ERPNext reporting section by this way but sill I have issue to override js file, remember any changes in original files will be lost by update.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this using the navbar settings present in v13 and above. Search for navbar settings using the awesome search bar :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Navbar Setting is a global setting and it is not based on user/roles.